# why is my Spring Boot application returning a 200 status on the browser, even though it throws a 409 (HTTP Conflict) status?

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, react-native, spring-data

I am having a function , in which i am checking whether a product have a rebooking status or not.

```
public GenericResponse checkingRebooking(@PathVariable @NotNull @NotEmpty String gatewayOrderId) {
        ShippingOrder shippingOrder = fetchSOForShipmentResolution(gatewayOrderId);
        if (b2bOrderService.boNeedsToDisableOtherOps(shippingOrder.getBaseOrder())) {
            logger.info("Rebooking is ongoing for this order, wait for some time to resolve shipment!!");
            return GenericResponse.builder ().statusCode (HttpStatus.OK).message ("true").build ();
        }
        return GenericResponse.builder ().statusCode (HttpStatus.OK).message ("false").build ();
    }
```

Here. fetchSOForShipmentResolution check whether the Id is in valid status or not . If it is not , then it throw  Conflict http exception .

```
public ShippingOrder fetchSOForShipmentResolution(String gatewayOrderId){
        ShippingOrder shippingOrder= shippingOrderService.findByGatewayOrderId(gatewayOrderId);
        return (shippingOrder != null)? shippingOrderService.verifyShipmentByGatewayOrderId(shippingOrder): null;
    }
```

```
public ShippingOrder verifyShipmentByGatewayOrderId(ShippingOrder shippingOrder){

        if(EnumShippingOrderStatus.getShipmentResolution().contains(shippingOrder.getShippingOrderStatus())){
            return shippingOrder;
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidDataException ("GatewayId does not have valid status.");
    }
```

Otherwise return shippingOrder (data).

When i searched the Id with not a valid status , it is returning with 200 status
[image]

But I want it to return with 409 error. How can I do so?

**When I debugged my code, it stops at the throw statement, which should throw a Conflict status. However, it is showing a 200 status in React.**

Comment: Why are you setting HttpStatus.OK in GenericResponse in both the cases? I think that could be the reason why. It would be better if you provide more code to look at.

Comment: Please remove the reactjs tag as this doesn't have anything to do with React.

Comment: Implementation of `fetchSOForShipmentResolution()` method is required here as a part of the question